# VMware - Read hosts clipboard without CTRL+v? Security issue?

Tags: vmware-workstation

When you have a file or some text on the hosts clipboard and you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> on a guest VM with VMware Tools installed, then the files will be copied or the text pasted in that guest VM.

Does the guest VM have access to the host clipboard content when I do NOT press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>?
For example by scanning the guests memory or VMware tools memory.
If so, would that not be a big security hole?